# Replacing html tags using regex and add_filter()

Tags: php, wordpress, regex-negation

I want to replace the `<h2 class="fusion-post-title">` tag with `<h1>` tag.

I've tested the regex on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and the capturing groups are there.

Is this proper way to do so? Maybe Wordpress is not triggering my `add_filter()`?

```
function replace_content($content){

    $content = preg_replace('#<h2 class="fusion-post-title"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/h2>#si', '<h1 class="fusion-post-title"${1}>${2}</h1>', $content);

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title isn't part of the content, hence your filter doesn't work. Last time I checked a Theme Fusion theme, the function they were using for generating titles *didn't* apply an filters that you could hook onto, but they did suggest that there are theme options for changing the tag used. See you have a couple of options:

1. You can search through the theme for `fusion-post-title` and see what functions come up, and whether there's any filters or options that you can use. Unfortunately, as it's a premium theme I don't have a recent copy to hand to check, otherwise I'd point you in the right direction.
2. You can edit the theme templates directly: **I'd recommend doing this to a child theme,** not the theme files directly. For more information on setting up a child theme, you should [refer to the codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Assuming you're going with option 2: once you've got your child theme set up (i.e. you've got your `functions.php` and `styles.css`), you can copy the relevant templates from the *parent* theme over to the *child* theme, and then edit them as you wish. If you take a look at Avada's `single.php` you'll notice something similar to:

```
<?php echo avada_render_post_title( $post->ID, false, '', '2' ); ?>
```

The last argument - `2` -  is the heading level to use (i.e `h2`). Simply change that to `1` and you should be good to go. Or replace it entirely with your own markup:

```
<h1 class="post_title"><?php the_title();?></h1>
```

Repeat this for which ever templates are required.

Comment: Thanks @Dre I really appreciate your help. If I use "the_title" I can get inside of the h2 tags, but I can't get beyond those. I didn't want to edit the core files, because when there's an update, things are much more likely to break. Simple things end up being such a big pain in the butt.

Comment: @InsuredApple There's probably theme options to change the tag: I'm looking at an old version of Avada, and it looks like there's option in there for changing the title tag, so you might not need to edit anything. If you *do* need to edit templates, you can create a child theme so that your changes are safe from updates.

Comment: got it. Thank you. I contacted them and they told me to edit the core files. I was hoping to write a plug-in or use Code Snippets to make the change. I'll start looking at Child Themes. Thank you ;)

Comment: @InsuredApple They told you to edit core files? Bananas. Child Themes are definitely the way to go.

Comment: hahaha, awesome. I will start looking at this. This is a copy/paste from them: h1 is only used for the title bar at the moment, if you want to use the h1 for the page title you will have to make code changes in the core files of avada theme.

Comment: @InsuredApple They really should make that setting filterable, or a theme option. Regardless, I've updated the answer above to point you in the right direction.

Comment: worked exactly like you suggested. It took a bit of digging. Downloaded the Child Theme template from Avada, copied over the single.php file, and passed in "1"... and it works :)